# How to alter multiple tables column datatype with if check?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query which will check multiple tables `date_created` and `date_updated` fields, so if these two field are having `datetime` datatype i want to remove that and add `varchar(4000)` datatype.

I have tried below but can't go forward.

```
IF EXIST ( evaluation_symptom_remedy, evaluation_symptom_cause ) ALTER
TABLE `evaluation_symptom_remedy` CHANGE `date_created` `date_created`
VARCHAR(4000) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

I want to update all tables `date_created` and `date_updated` field if they are having `datetime` datatype. I want that datatype set to `varchar`.

Comment: Something is going very wrong if you're changing the data types of two columns with names clearly indicating that they should contain date (or datetime) data and you're changing the data type to something *vastly* less appropriate for storing such data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes i want to change it to string. Date-time isn't supported by our server. I can change it to timestamp also however i need to know the right query so that i can try now.

Comment: why you are trying to change the column datatype .. instead try to cast or convert the data which you are sending it to your server ( you can make your columns datatype from the beginning varchar and save the date as a string

Comment: You could query information_schema.columns to find the tables you are interested in.